# Handling custom exception classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I am developing a MVC application.

I am trying to define my own exception classes. I am making this structure first time...

What else I have to add in my exception classes , like constructor or something , so it work well... ?

```
 public ActionResult Edit(EmployeeVM employeeVM)
    {
                EmployeeService employeeService = new PartyService();
                try
                {
                    PartyService partyService = new PartyService();
                     partyService.Update(PartyVM);
                }
                catch (DuplicateEntityExcpetion e)
                {
                    TempData["error"] = e + "Party you are trying to add is already exist.";
                }

                catch (InvalidDataException e)
                {
                    TempData["error"] =  e + "Data which you are trying to add is not valid.";
                }


               public class InvalidDataException : Exception
               {
               }

               public class DuplicateEntityExcpetion : Exception
               {
               }
    }
```

Comment: Note that `e + "some string"` will call `Exception.ToString()` which will output almost everything about the exception, including the stack trace.  I suspect you want `e.Message + "some string"`

Answer (score 0):

You must throw these exceptions from your service so that they get catched here.

```
throw new DuplicateEntityExcpetion("Your Query or Message");
throw new InvalidDataException ("Your Query or Message");
```

Also, it is a good practice to have a generic exception handled so that you have taken care of all exceptions.

```
 catch (Exception e)
                {
                    TempData["error"] =  e + "Data which you are trying to add is not valid.";
                }
```